# Handling multiple persistant volumes for a Rethinkdb Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, rethinkdb, docker-swarm

I'm currently using `RethinkDB` across cloud servers by manually joining each server at setup. I'm interested in moving over to a `Swarm` approach to make scaling and failover easier. The current approach is cumbersome to scale.

In the current manual approach, I simply create a local folder on each server for `RDB` and mount as a volume to store its data. However, using a `Swarm` means that I'd need to handle volumes more dynamically. Each container will need a distinct volume to keep data separate in case of errors.

Any recommendations on how to handle this scenario? A lot of the tutorials I've seen so far mention Flocker to manage persistent storage, but I can't see that being handled dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am struggling with a situation like this. I've created a temporary fix with GlusterFS.

What you do is install GlusterFS on all the Docker nodes and mount the folders. This way the data exists on all the nodes. But this is less than ideal if you have a lot of writes. This could be slow because of the way Gluster treats your data replication to prevent data loss. It is solid, but I have some issues with the speed.

In your case I would suggest looking into Flocker. Flocker is a volume plugin that migrates your data when a container moves to another host. I haven't had any experience with it, but in my case the concept of Flocker renders useless, I need my data in multiple containers on multiple hosts (Read only) This is where Gluster came into play